# Knowing solution of ${\bf A x} = {\bf b}$, find solution for ${\bf A}^\top {\bf x} = {\bf b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, transpose

Suppose that ${\bf A} \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ is invertible, ${\bf b} \in \Bbb R^{n}$. Knowing a solution of ${\bf A} {\bf x}_1 = {\bf b}$, find a solution for ${\bf A}^\top {\bf x}_2 = {\bf b}$. Express ${\bf x}_2$ without inverting $\bf A$.

---

This question isn't my homework. It's related with my programming problem. I'm not even sure whether this problem is solvable.

Comment: Downvotes are probably due to lack of effort; people will think you’re trying to get someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: Explaining that kind of context usually leads to a much better reception to your question.

Comment: Hint: you already know $b$, so substitute into the second equation.

Comment: I think there's no simple general way to do this. If/when A has a special form, maybe, ...

Comment: How are you solving $A x_1 = b$ in the first place? Often one computes an LU factorization $A = LU$ then uses backsubstitution to efficiently solve $Ly = b$ and $Ux_1 = y$. It follows from $A = LU$ that $A^T = U^T L^T$. So once you have an LU factorization of $A$, you also have an LU factorization of $A^T$, which you can use to solve $A^T x_2 = b$ efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any way to do it. Of course you can write
$$x_2 = A^{-T}Ax_1$$
but unless $A$ has a special form (is orthogonal, for instance) I don't see any way to compute the right-hand side without solving a linear system. You have that
$$x_1 \cdot b = x_2 \cdot b$$
which does characterize $x_2$ in one dimension, but not higher.

(Naturally you never materialize an inverse matrix in numerical methods... you would use LU decomposition or another matrix solver to solve
$$A^T x_2 = Ax_1$$
for $x_2$.)

Comment: Matrix A doesn't have additional properties. So as you have written this problem cannot be solved purely (without approximation). I will try to use some decomposition method (that's not strictly related with this problem so I won't post more about my solution), thanks for your answer!